# Animating a UIView in a .xib file

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, clock

I've made a program in Xcode that tells the time. I want to have a rectangle that animates/grows longer as the seconds increase (time progresses), and starts again when the seconds reach 60 (and go back to 0). I don't have storyboarding and have already started so I don't want to go back and start again.

Should I use a `UIView` instance and animate the 'frame' property?

Here is my clock code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self updateTime];

[super viewDidLoad];

hourFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
hourFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH";
minuteFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
minuteFormatter.dateFormat = @"mm";
secondFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
secondFormatter.dateFormat = @"ss";    
}

- (void)updateTime {

[updateTimer invalidate];
updateTimer = nil;

currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

hourLabel.text = [hourFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
minuteLabel.text = [minuteFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
secondLabel.text = [secondFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];

updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Should I use a UIView instance and animate the 'frame' property?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a `UIView` and animate its frame.

You shouldn't necessarily do this using a timer though, just set the animation to run for the full duration and the complete frame height change and use a timer to restart the next animation. This will give the smoothest animation.

For updating the time display you only need a timer running once per second.

Look at running the animation like this:

```
CGRect frame = self.expandingTimeView.frame;
frame.height = 0;
self.expandingTimeView.frame = frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:60
                 animations:^{
    frame.height = MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT;
    self.expandingTimeView.frame = frame;
}];
```

There's a good guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html).

This code would go in your `updateTime` method, which I'm assuming would be called each minute by a timer. You need to correct the name of `expandingTimeView` for whatever your view property is called, and you need to replace `MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT` with the maximum height the view should grow to during the animation.

You may want to have 2 methods, 1 containing the view animation (`updateTimeView`), called each minute and 1 containing the label text update (`updateTimeLabels`), called each second. In this case the 2 timers should be created in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, would you mind showing me how I would declare and implement this animation? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to Objective-C; I've declared a UIView and linked it to the .xib file. Whereabouts should i place your code, and do I need to declare anything new, change variable names, etc?